# Angular error TS2322 My object is not assignable to type 'MyTypeName | undefined'

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I want to change some things like reading a nested json and I get an error.

This is my interface

```
export interface Formation {
    id: number;
    slug: string;
    name: string;
    website: string;
    description: string;
    cursus : Cursus;
  }

  export interface Cursus{
    
      cursusid: number;
    filiere: string;
    level: string;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    href: string;
    describe: string;
    
  }
```

This is MyDetailComponents

```
export class FormationDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  formation!: Formation | undefined  | undefined
 
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
    const formationIdFromRoute = Number(routeParams.get('formationId'));
  
    
    this.formation = formations.find(formation => formation.id === formationIdFromRoute);
   

   
  }
```

And I have a error with this :

```
this.formation = formations.find(formation => formation.id === formationIdFromRoute);
```

```
error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; slug: string; name: string; website: string; description: string; cursus: { cursusid: number; filiere: string; level: string; name: string; slug: string; href: string; describe: string; }[]; } | { ...; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Formation | undefined'.

 Type '{ id: number; slug: string; name: string; website: string; description: string; cursus: { cursusid: number; filiere: string; level: string; name: string; slug: string; href: string; describe: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Formation'.
    Types of property 'cursus' are incompatible.
      Type '{ cursusid: number; filiere: string; level: string; name: string; slug: string; href: string; describe: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Cursus': cursusid, Filiere, Level, name, and 3 more.
```

I try to change my interface with multiple solution for exemple

```
cursus : Cursus[];
```

but it doesn't work

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show the `formations` type and its used class/interface? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the `Formation` interface to use array of `Cursus[]` and treat it as array if items? Then you can `push, shift, unshit, pop` items from that array?

```js
export interface Formation {
    id: number;
    slug: string;
    name: string;
    website: string;
    description: string;
    cursus : Cursus[];
  }
```